# Deleted all the files from /usr/lib/apache2/modules directory!

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 10.04, somehow I deleted all the files in /usr/lib/apache2/modules, is there a way I can get them back or set it to default installation?

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a list of the apache related packages you have installed:

```
 $ dpkg -l | grep apache
```

To search the files that are associated with each package:

```
$ dpkg -L <package name> | grep  /usr/lib/apache2/modules
```

To reinstall packages that match the search:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install <package name>
```